# Intellij run shortcut (mac)

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Run is ^R (CTRL R), but it doesn't work on a mac.

Is there anyway I can re-write the shortcut to use OPTION R or something?

Answer (score 4):

You can change the binding at
Preferences -> Keymap -> Main menu -> Run -> Run

As for why ^R doesn't work, are you by any chance using the IdeaVim plugin?  It grabs ^R for Redo (the usual vim ^R binding), and -- unfortunately -- no indication of that appears in the IntelliJ keymap.

Answer (score 3):

In default, `Run` is not `Ctrl + R` in Windows/Linux (it's `Shift + F10`), but it is `^R` in Mac.

Maybe you have another keymapping, check it under `File` -> `Settings` -> `Keymap` -> `Main menu` -> `Run` -> `Run`.

Comment: I thought `^R` was `Ctrl + R` on a mac? If I'm wrong, what's `^R`?

Comment: Symbol `^` [means Ctrl](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236), that's correct. Maybe you have (accidently) changed the keymapping? Or there is no `Run Configuration`?

Comment: Doesn't work me either. Double checked in configuration and it's indeed ^R.  It seems to be the key above control, but clicking shift doesn't work. Man I hate this...trying 10 mins to figure out a keymapping is no fun. If I switch from MAC to Windows, it's super clear: Shift + F10.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the Keymap option in intellij-idea to figure out what shortcuts you really need?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, I am using equipment below and if I press `control` + `r`, then I can see how code is executed and its result:

[image]

[image]

[image]